# How to empty a node with SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to empty a node (remove its children) with `SimpleXML`, but I am left with a lot of whitespace. I've tried adding `text()` to the xpath selector to delete any text nodes, but it doesn't seem to work:

```php
$previous = $includePathNode->xpath('path|text()');
foreach ($previous as $node) {
    // Delete node
    unset($node[0]);
}
```

All the whitespace between `<path>` nodes is still preserved though.

Note: I use xpath `path` for forward compatibility considerations: If someone decides to add some other content to the parent node than `<path>` nodes, then cowardly don't delete these. So please take *empty* to have this meaning in this context.

Example:

```xml
<include_path>
    <path />
    <path />
    <path />
    <x />
</include_path>
```

Result according to my code:

```xml
<include_path>
    
    
    
    <x />
</include_path>
```

Expected:

```xml
<include_path><x /></include_path>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short representative xml sample, before and after the deletion?

Comment: @JackFleeting Done

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `LIBXML_NOBLANKS` option when you load the string:

```
$string = "<include_path>
    <path />
    <path />
    <path />
    <x />
</include_path>
";                                                                       
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, null, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$target = $xml->xpath("//path");
foreach ($target as $node) {
   unset($node[0]);
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<include_path><x/></include_path>
```

If you want to suppress the xml version header, you have to do an extra step:

```
$domxml = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
echo $domxml->ownerDocument->saveXML($domxml->ownerDocument->documentElement);
```

and the output becomes just

```
<include_path><x/></include_path>
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be an option but it's a bit excessive, reformatting the entire XML. I would be more happy to just remove whitespace where I'm fiddling, if at all possible. The `include_path` node in the example above is just a node in a larger XML. Problems with reformatting everything include readability, source control, etc. So I'd be very happy to just hack around where I'm hacking around.

Comment: @Dinu I understand, but you should have mentioned it in the question itself.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear: "I'm trying to empty *a node*". Conversely, I cannot elaborate a question that contains everything I don't want to do. The question is specific enough about removing whitespace from a single node, using SimpleXML.